# Memory error while downloading large Gzip files and decompressing them

Tags: python, gzip

I am trying to download a dataset from https://datasets.imdbws.com/title.principals.tsv.gz, decompress the contents in my code itself(Python)and write the resulting file(s) onto disk.

To do so I am using the following code snippet.

```
results = requests.get(config[sourceFiles]['url'])
    with open(config[sourceFiles]['downloadLocation']+config[sourceFiles]['downloadFileName'], 'wb') as f_out:
        print(config[sourceFiles]['downloadFileName'] + " starting download")
        f_out.write(gzip.decompress(results.content))
        print(config[sourceFiles]['downloadFileName']+" downloaded successfully")
```

This code works fine for most zip files however for larger files it gives the following error message.

```
File "C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\gzip.py", line 532, in decompress
    return f.read()
  File "C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\gzip.py", line 276, in read
    return self._buffer.read(size)
  File "C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\gzip.py", line 471, in read
    uncompress = self._decompressor.decompress(buf, size)
MemoryError
```

Is there a way to accomplish this without having to download the zip file directly onto disk and decompressing it for actual data.

Comment: gzip compression is not the same as a zip archive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a **streaming** request coupled with `zlib`:

```
import zlib
import requests

url = 'https://datasets.imdbws.com/title.principals.tsv.gz'
result = requests.get(url, stream=True)
f_out = open("result.txt", "wb")
chunk_size = 1024 * 1024

d = zlib.decompressobj(zlib.MAX_WBITS|32)

for chunk in result.iter_content(chunk_size):
    buffer = d.decompress(chunk)
    f_out.write(buffer)

buffer = d.flush()
f_out.write(buffer)

f_out.close()
```

This snippet reads the data chunk by chunk and feeds it to zlib which can handle data streams.
Depending on your connection speed and CPU/disk performance you can test various chunk sizes.

Comment: Were you able to use the streaming code? In my tests the memory usage did not go over 45 MB.

Comment: thanks for the answer. This seems to be working fine. I tried applying stream/chunk logic using gzip package decompression but that ended up throwing *EOFError: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached*. Guess the magic is in how zlib handles decompression.
[link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html)

Comment: Yes, it's just how the the gzip module is designed.